# Change in perspective name not appearing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I have a plugin in which I have created a perspective. Now I changed the name of the perspective in plugin.xml. It is working fine if I am running from sources. The name of the perspective still the older one when I export the plugin. I am using eclipse juno 4.2

I am completely lost no clue whatsoever. I checked the plugin.xml file in the exported plugin it is having the new name. What is the mistake I am making???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was adding perspectives and views using the plugin.XML, changes didn't take effect because when running plugin projects in development environment eclipse creates a **"runtime-(pluginProjectName).application**" folder in the parent of the workspace directory.

If you delete this folder eclipse should run with the new changes made to Views and Perspectives structure.

Best of luck.

Comment: The usage of the -clean switch in the launch or product file for your application should also help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html This link helped me in solving it. I should have searched in this line earlier itself. I hope this helps for someone else. Do clean your eclipse in case of these kind of problems